# VB.NET 4.0 program stops responding System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a small simple program in VB.NET with 4.0 as the target. Everything works fine on my computer and other computers that have Visual Studio installed. The problem arises when another computer tries to run the program, without any special error message it just stops responding when you launched it :/. I managed to find the error message `System.InvalidOperationException` and the error code `clr20r3`.

I have tried the program on both Windows 7 and Windows 8 machines, I'm using Windows 8 by the way.
Another thing I would like to mention is that I'm not too good at VB.net I only know the basics of the langue.

Here are all the related Windows logs and project file from Visual Studio 2012: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k1ksi6ri9qger93/Clicker.rar

Appreciate all the help I can get with this
Thanks in advance!

PS Let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: Suggest added exception handler around the entry point (and [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception)) that captures the exception type, message and stack trace (ideally recursively if `InnerException` is not null) so at least you know where it is failing. A process dump (which VS can open) would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll`, but you're not including it in your Publish Application Files (it's set to prerequisite), nor is it selected in the prerequisites section.

Does it help to include it in the Application Files / Prerequisites?

To accomplish this, open your Project Properties, and goto the `Publish` tab. In there is an `Application Files` directory button . If you change your PowerPacks dll to `included` in that list, perhaps it could help.

Comment: Thanx for the reply, but since I'm not too good at VB I don't really know what Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll is :/ If you got time could you try what you are suggesting using my project file?

Comment: The solution works fine here, but of course, I too have Visual Studio installed, so not a good test. Is the project file you've uploaded exactly the same as the one you're having trouble with?

Comment: Ya, it's exactly the same, although I have had this problem with other programs I've done too.

Comment: Seems like I found a fix, or at least a quick fix, I saw another post on here taking about the same thing as @PGallagher did "Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll" so I removed the LineShape and the RectangelShape in the form and then sent it to a friend, he confirmed that it worked!

Comment: Cool... Glad you got it working... I sort of helped I suppose! You should be able to include that dll in your ClickOnce publish, reinclude your line and rectangle, and that should sort it!

Comment: Yeah, thanx! Though is there some way I can include the dll in my debug exe? Since I rather would send someone a executable file rather than something they have to install in order to run, if you know what I mean! Thanx again!

Comment: Not really I'm afraid, some options are to try to replace your lines and rectangles with images maybe? Or perhaps think about using WPF instead of windows forms which should give you more options for graphics. However, with WPF, you may still need to reference dll's....

Comment: Okay, I guess I have to avoid the PowerPacks.dll dependent files if I wan't to send someone the debug exe file... Anyway thanx for all the help!! :D